# How to find out if running script/command as root/sudo using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, centos8

I am following https://lifehacker.com/add-a-handy-separator-between-commands-in-your-terminal-5840450 to create a nice separator between commands in the terminal in Linux. Specifically, CentOS 8.

I am trying to modify the script to output the username of the user who ran the command.

[Here](https://github.com/Ajhad1/emilis-config/blob/master/.bash_ps1) is what I came up with.

```
# Fill with minuses
# (this is recalculated every time the prompt is shown in function prompt_command):
fill="--- "

reset_style='\[\033[00m\]'
if [ -z "$VIM" ];
then status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90m\]' # gray color; use 0;37m for lighter color
else status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90;107m\]'
fi
prompt_style=$reset_style
command_style=$reset_style'\[\033[1;29m\]' # bold black
# Prompt variable:

OLD_PS1="$PS1"
PS1="$status_style"'$fill $USER \t\n'"$prompt_style$OLD_PS1$command_style"

# Reset color for command output
# (this one is invoked every time before a command is executed):
trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m"' DEBUG


function prompt_command {

    # create a $fill of all screen width minus the time string and a space and USER and a space:
    let fillsize=${COLUMNS}-10-${#USER}
    fill=""
    while [ "$fillsize" -gt "0" ]
    do
        fill="-${fill}" # fill with underscores to work on 
        let fillsize=${fillsize}-1
    done

    # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
    case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        bname=`basename "${PWD/$HOME/~}"`
        echo -ne "\033]0;${bname}: ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac

}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Line 15 added " " and `$USER` to what is generated.

Line 25 changed to include an extra space and the length of the variable `$USER`

It looks just like I want it to.

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1kIo.png)

But, I would like to update the code to output if I ran a command as `sudo` or not. 
Ideally, it would change the name to root or whatever the root user name is.

I have tried several things, mainly I tried using `whoami` but this always returns my username not root. 
If I run `sudo whoami` I get root but not from the script.
I also tried `EUID` No dice.

At this point, I have left the code in working condition with the `$USER` reference but I am willing to change it to whatever it needs to be.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thank you I will try that. While searching online the closest question to mine was posted here so I thought I would give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution provided by [u/pLumo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590493/415883)

> Solution Limitations:
>
> - There are cases not covered, for example sudo --user=some_user .... I think it's fairly easy to further enhance the awk script.
> - As it relies on the history, it won't work with commands you do not have in history, e.g. when using HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth and issue a command with a space in front.

```
# Fill with minuses
# (this is recalculated every time the prompt is shown in function prompt_command):
fill="--- "

reset_style='\[\033[00m\]'
if [ -z "$VIM" ];
then status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90m\]' # gray color; use 0;37m for lighter color
else status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90;107m\]'
fi
prompt_style=$reset_style
command_style=$reset_style'\[\033[1;29m\]' # bold black
# Prompt variable:

OLD_PS1="$PS1"
PS1="$status_style"'$fill $name \t\n'"$prompt_style$OLD_PS1$command_style"

# Reset color for command output
# (this one is invoked every time before a command is executed):
trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m"' DEBUG


function prompt_command {

    # create a $fill of all screen width minus the time string and a space and USER and a space:
    name=$(fc -l -1 | awk -v u="$USER" '{if ($2=="sudo") { if ($3=="-u") u=$4; else u="root"; }; printf "%s",u}')
    let fillsize=${COLUMNS}-10-${#name}
    fill=""
    while [ "$fillsize" -gt "0" ]
    do
        fill="-${fill}" # fill with underscores to work on 
        let fillsize=${fillsize}-1
    done

    # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
    case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        bname=`basename "${PWD/$HOME/~}"`
        echo -ne "\033]0;${bname}: ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac

}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Terminal output:

[image: Terminal Output - Solution]

Not sure if I should delete this question or not. Or if there is a better way to adjust this. Open to suggestions.

Comment: Thank you John for fixing it for me.